# How to Display images in a row and next to each other plus view png & gif ASP

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

The code below first displays folders as hyperlinks, you can click into these folders and if they contain JPG's it will display them.

Is it possible to make these images display in a row and also to show the PNG's & GIF's in the folder also.

```
<%
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0

qfolder = request.querystring("f")
if qfolder = "" then
    folderspec = server.mappath(".")
    Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Set demofolder = filesys.GetFolder(folderspec) 
    Set folcoll = demofolder.SubFolders
    For Each subfol in folcoll
        folsize = left((subfol.size/1000000), 3)
        folist = folist & "<a href='?f=" & subfol.name & "'><strong title='view'></strong> " & subfol.Name & "" & vbcrlf
        folist = folist & "<BR>"  
    Next
    set filesys = nothing
    Response.Write folist

else

filepath = server.mappath(".") & "\" & qfolder
captionfile = filepath & "\captions.txt"
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim SomeArray()
'caption part
    If filesys.FileExists(captionfile) then
        set file = filesys.GetFile(captionfile)
        Set TextStream = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading,TristateUseDefault)
        captioncount = 0
        Do While Not TextStream.AtEndOfStream
            Line = TextStream.readline
            ReDim Preserve SomeArray(captioncount)
            SomeArray(captioncount) = line
            'response.write captioncount & " " & somearray(captioncount) & "<br>"
            captioncount = captioncount + 1
            'Response.write Line
        Loop
        textStream.close
    end if

'folder part
    Set demofolder = filesys.GetFolder(filepath) 
    Set filecoll = demofolder.Files
    filecount = 0
    For Each file in filecoll
        Ext = UCase(Right(File.Path, 3)) 
        If Ext = "JPG" OR Ext = "GIF" Then
        on error resume next
        data = SomeArray(filecount)
        on error goto 0
        hrefpath = qfolder & "/" & file.name
        imagepath = "<strong>" & data & "</strong><br><a href='" & hrefpath & "' title='free image gallery' border=0><img src='" & hrefpath & "' border='" & border_size & "' title=""" & data & """ style='border-color: " & border_color & ";'></a><br>"
        filist = filist & imagepath & vbcrlf
        filist = filist & "<BR>"
        filecount = filecount + 1
        data = ""
        end if
    Next
    set filesys = Nothing
    filist = filist & "<br><small><a href='http://www.allscoop.com/' target='_blank'>allscoop free image gallery</a></small>"
%>

<h3><a href="." title="up one level">&#171;</a>
&nbsp;<%=qfolder%></h3>

<p><%=filist%></p>

<% end if %>
```

Thanks
Ross

Comment: I suggest you put a screenshot of the current and optionally of the ideal situation.
And I suggest you use methods in stead of long long blocks of code (I'm not familiar with VB though)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove the final 2